# Pr column missing from coefficients if summary is not called first

Tags: r, linear-regression

The following prints two result sets

```
fit.all <-lm(target ~ .,train )
summary(fit.all) # If I comment out this line then coefs does not include P value
coef(summary(fit.all)) -> coefs 
print(coefs)
```

However if I comment out the first call to print then the second result set does not include Pr
Why?

[Update]

I can no longer get the p values at all.
working on reproducing.

[Update]

I can get at the values this way but I am unsure how to access the Pr column

```
coef(summary(fit.all)) -> fit.all.summary.coef 
str(fit.all.summary.coef) 
class(fit.all.summary.coef)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag and in particular questions should be complete including all inputs (using `dput`) so that it is reproducible so others can copy and paste the code to their session to reproduce the problem.  Note that the `lm` code should be written `lm(target ~., train)` and `coef(...)` should be used -- not `$coefficients`.

Comment: Question updated. Is it OK now?

Comment: It is still not reproducible and you need `coef(summary(fit.all))` .  Do not use $whatever when there exists an accessor function for that.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided a dataset to work with, but I suspect it is because of the way you have coded your script. Here is an example with R's `iris` dataset. Instead of doing it the way you used, I just saved the summary of the model as an object and pulled the coefficients directly from there:

```
#### Fit Model ####
fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width,
          data = iris)

#### Save Summary as Object ####
sum.fit <- summary(fit)

#### Print Directly ####
sum.fit$coefficients
print(sum.fit$coefficients) # same thing if you want it
```

This pulls the coefficients and p values directly from the saved summary, which is what I suspect you needed:

```
              Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  6.5262226  0.4788963 13.627631 6.469702e-28
Sepal.Width -0.2233611  0.1550809 -1.440287 1.518983e-01
```

Note that running `coef(fit)` only gives you the coefficients and none of the other estimates:

```
(Intercept) Sepal.Width 
  6.5262226  -0.2233611
```

Comment: I can repeat the desired behaviour with your example but not with my dataset

Comment: Could you share your data or a subset of your data in the comments? Could possibly provide more direct advice that way :)

Comment: Thank you, but sorry I cant do that.

Comment: No worries. Perhaps if you can simulate your data in some way and try posting that, you won't have to use your own personal data if that is an issue.

Comment: I updated the question. I think I have the data now but I don't know how to access it.

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to access it? Like you don't know how to share it here or don't know how to get it to load into R?

Comment: Oh nvm just saw your answer

Answer (score 1):

I was able to access the PR column this way
I wonder if it had to do with the PR values being extremely small  < 2e^{-16}

```
fit.all <-lm(target ~ .,train )
coef(summary(fit.all)) -> fit.all.summary.coef
colnames<-colnames(train) 
n= length(colnames)  
cat(" n is ",n,"\n")
tvals <-fit.all.summary.coef[,3]
pvals <-fit.all.summary.coef[,4]
pval <- rep(0,n)
for ( i in 1:n)
{
   cat(colnames[i],tvals[i],pvals[i],"\n")
}
```